# Setting Cache-Control header in Nuxt JS works on localhost but not in production

Tags: node.js, http-headers, nuxt.js, vercel

As I am deploying my Nuxt JS universal app on Zeit Now, I was trying to take advantage of Zeit's `Cache-Control` header which is mentioned in [Zeit Cache Doc](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/network/caching/#serverless-functions-(lambdas)).

Then I tried to look for how can I add the `Cache-Control` header in my Nuxt JS app and fortunately found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2554) which was explaining the same thing.

Now as I was using `serverMiddleware` anyways in my Nuxt app to get the currently logged-in user's data using `firebase-admin`, so I thought I would easily add the response header in my code and so I did. In my `/serverMiddleware/handleCookie.js` I have it like this:

```js
const Cookies = require('cookies')
const admin = require('../services/firebase-admin-init')

export default async (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=1000, stale-while-revalidate')

  try {
    const authUser = await verifyCookie(req, res)

    if (authUser) {
      const userData = await fetchUserDetailsFromFirestore(
        req,
        authUser.uid,
        authUser.email_verified
      )

      if (userData) {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Now the crazy thing is when I run dev i.e. `yarn nuxt` and check my site over localhost, I can easily see my added header in Chrome Network Tool.

[image: header showing up in localhost]

But when I push my project to Zeit Now for hosting using `now --prod` and check my actual site, I do not see this header.

[image: no header in production]

Now I am not understanding if I am doing something wrong, cause if I did, it should not have shown up in the localhost dev response header. I spend many days trying to fix this but went nowhere. Go no clue why this is happening. I am also using [nuxt/now-builder](https://github.com/nuxt/now-builder) for the Zeit deployment and here is my `now.json` file.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "regions": ["bom1"],
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": [
          "services/firebase-admin-init.js",
          "serverMiddleware/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If anyone can help in this matter, it would be really helpful.

Comment: are you add   serverMiddleware: [
    '/serverMiddleware/handleCookie.js'
  ],

Comment: @Pablote ofcourse man....

Answer (score 4):

Your bug is related to time and async. In dev, everything works fast, but in prod, you need to wait longer for the promises to be resolved, the server is a little slow. Should be happening something like if authUser but not userdata, in this case you not has next() function.

I refactoring your middleware, the following code structure should help.

```js
export default (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=1000, stale-while-revalidate')

  verifyCookie(req, res)
    .then((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        fetchUserDetailsFromFirestore(
          req,
          authUser.uid,
          authUser.email_verified
        )
          .then(() => {
            next()
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
          })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I will try it out and hopefully, it will work. Right now I am upvoting it as I cannot test it now. After the test I will mark it as the answer. Thank you so so much... Can't thank you enough.
The reason I didn't have an else for the if not userData is because there is no possibility of this happening unless someone goes to the production firestore db and delete that user data while keeping the firebase auth. Lol! I thought it's crazy... :D

Comment: iSaumya – it would be great if you could add your final experience / final script here, so others know, if this is really a correct and working answer. Thank you!