# How to handle file versioning and caching for NUXT.js deployed on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting, static-site-generation

I use NUXT3 to generate "Static Site Generation" files with hash version, and deploy static file hosting to  "Firebase HOSTING".
The browser client is lazy-loading JavaScript files when navigating to each page.

The problem is: when I deploy a new version, the Firebase hosting deletes the old files and replaces them with the new version of files with a different hash, so the client who is using the old version (not reloaded the page yet) cannot access other pages because JavaScript files with hash are all deleted meaning the old files are no longer exist.

Do you have any solution or any advice for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider testing the approach illustrated in "[Setting Cache-Control header in Nuxt JS works on localhost but not in production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58596057/6309)"

```js
export default async (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=1000, stale-while-revalidate')
  ...
}
```

It sets the `Cache-Control` header to `'s-maxage=1000, stale-while-revalidate'`: This means that the content will be considered stale after 1000 seconds, but it will still be served to the client while a revalidation request is made in the background to fetch the new content.

That alone might not be enough, though.

---

You can also consider employing a strategy where you do not immediately delete the old hashed files. Instead, keep them for a period of time to ensure that users who are on the old version still have access to the necessary files.
This can be combined with a prompt to the user to reload the page whenever a new version is available.

You would need to implement a service worker and to use the `skipWaiting()` method to ensure that the latest version is activated as soon as it is ready.

---

In details:

You can use the [`@nuxtjs/pwa` module](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/) to easily add a service worker to your Nuxt.js project (`npm install @nuxtjs/pwa`).
Add `@nuxtjs/pwa` to the `modules` section of your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/pwa',
],
```

[Configure your service worker](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/setup#configuration) by adding a `pwa` key in your `nuxt.config.js` file. Under this key, you can configure the `workbox` property to define caching strategies for your assets.
For example, using the [Workbox module](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/workbox/):

```js
pwa: {
    workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
        urlPattern: '/*',
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        method: 'GET',
        },
        {
        urlPattern: '/_nuxt/*',
        handler: 'CacheFirst',
        method: 'GET',
        },
    ],
    },
},
```

Here, the first rule uses the `NetworkFirst` strategy for all requests, which tries to fetch the latest content from the network, and falls back to cached content if the network is unavailable.
The second rule caches assets in the `/_nuxt/` directory using the `CacheFirst` strategy, which serves assets from the cache but updates the cache in the background.
This is inspired from "[Create and List Offline-Available Pages in PWAs](https://betterprogramming.pub/create-offline-available-pages-in-pwas-5136edea7de1)" from [Harry Theo](https://www.harrytheo.com/about/).

The `@nuxtjs/pwa` module automatically registers the service worker for you. However, if you are not using this module, you will need to manually register the service worker by creating a file (e.g. `sw-register.js`) and include it in your project:

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
        console.log('Service Worker registered with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
    });
    });
}
```

Normally, when you have a new version of the service worker, the new service worker is installed but not yet activated. It waits until there are no pages still using the old service worker.
By calling `skipWaiting()`, you can force the new service worker to activate immediately.

The service worker itself, typically named something like `sw.js` or `service-worker.js` should be placed at the root of your web directory or as close to it as possible. It is registered by the `sw-register.js` above, which is included in your main HTML page.

That service worker  `sw.js` incorporates `self.skipWaiting()` and `clients.claim()`, and would look like:

```js
const CACHE_NAME = 'cache-v1';
const ASSETS = [
  '/index.html',
  '/css/styles.css',
  '/js/app.js',
  // ... additional assets ...
];

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  // Force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker.
  self.skipWaiting(); // <-- This is new

  // Cache the application assets during the installation phase.
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(ASSETS);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  // Take control of the page and start serving new content immediately.
  clients.claim(); // <-- This is new
  
  // Delete old cache versions.
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheName !== CACHE_NAME) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Respond with cached assets, or fetch them from the network if not in cache.
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

By using `self.skipWaiting()` in the `install` event listener and `clients.claim()` in the `activate` event listener, you ensure that the new service worker takes control immediately and starts serving the new assets as soon as they are available.

The `self.skipWaiting()` is used during the `install` phase of the service worker. This tells the service worker to become active as soon as it is installed, without waiting for the old service worker to be released.

And during the activation phase, you can see that it tries to delete old caches that are not in the whitelist, and claims control of the currently open pages with `self.clients.claim()`. This ensures that the latest assets are used immediately, and you can notify users to reload the page to get the latest version.

**This approach helps to address the issue of users being stuck on an older version because the old hashed files are deleted immediately upon deployment of a new version.**

**Instead, the old files are cached and are still accessible until the new service worker takes over and updates the cached assets.**

Once you have configured your service worker, you can build your Nuxt.js project and deploy it to Firebase Hosting as usual. The service worker will start caching assets and handling network requests, following your configuration.

When you deploy a new version of your application, browsers will detect a change in your service worker script and attempt to register a new service worker.
As illustrated above, you do listen for events such as `install`, `activate`, and `fetch` to control how the new service worker takes control and how it caches new assets.

---

I thought that was another approach: "[Manage live & preview channels, releases, and versions for your site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-hosting-resources)"

[image: https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/hosting/images/hosting-single-site-hierarchy.png]

> The content and configuration served by each channel is packaged into a version object that has a unique identifier.
> When you deploy to your site, Firebase creates a **release object** that points to a specific version.
> A release contains metadata about the deployment, like who deployed and when they deployed.

But that only means, for your live channel, that keeping previous releases enables you to roll back to a previous version of your site, if needed.
You do not have two versions of a live channel up at the same time...